# How to export underline texts in pdf using PyMuPDF?

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction, pymupdf

I have a pdf document that have section numbers like 4.1.1 that are underlined. How would I go about using PyMuPDF to extract texts that are underlined?

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Comment: Please share your code.